# read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on_bad_lines'

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read multiple dataframes in an list like the following:

```
for i in excels:
    df2 = pd.read_csv(i, on_bad_lines='skip')
    dfs.append(df2)
```

and it is working fine while running it locally but when on the deployement it shows the following error:

```
TypeError at /rfid-dumpdownload/
read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on_bad_lines'
```

`on_bad_lines` is even in the documentation then why is it not accepting it ?

Answer (score 2):

In the newer version of pandas `error_bad_lines` is replaced by `on_bad_lines` with `Str` value [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Answer (score 1):

Reason is use older pandas version, under pandas 1.4.0:

> on_bad_lines{‘error’, ‘warn’, ‘skip’} or callable, default ‘error’

```
Specifies what to do upon encountering a bad line (a line with too many fields). Allowed values are :

        ‘error’, raise an Exception when a bad line is encountered.

        ‘warn’, raise a warning when a bad line is encountered and skip that line.

        ‘skip’, skip bad lines without raising or warning when they are encountered.

New in version 1.3.0:

    callable, function with signature (bad_line: list[str]) -> list[str] | None that will process a single bad line. bad_line is a list of strings split by the sep. If the function returns None, the bad line will be ignored. If the function returns a new list of strings with more elements than expected, a ParserWarning will be emitted while dropping extra elements. Only supported when engine="python"

New in version 1.4.0.
```

Comment: What do I need to change exactly ?

Comment: @RahulSharma - is not possible upgrade pandas?

Comment: for latest version of pandas do: pip install --upgrade  pandas

Comment: For specific version (e.g. 1.4.0) do: pip install 'pandas==1.4.0'

Answer (score 1):

Use `error_bad_lines` argument instead of `on_bad_lines`.

In the newer version of pandas `error_bad_lines` is replaced by `on_bad_lines`

Comment: share some example with version details

Answer (score 0):

The *error_bad_lines* argument from Pandas *read_csv* is **deprecated**. So you should use the *on_bad_lines* argument instead.

Here you have the *error_bad_lines* documentation: [doc error_bad_lines](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Here you have the *on_bad_lines* documentation: [doc on_bad_lines](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of error_bad_lines use on_bad_lines

so if you want to skip the error lines just as you do in `error_bad_lines = True`
Do

```
on_bad_lines = "skip"
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Check this out!!

This is the new syntax to use